# Sorting data onto a different file

Tags: python

I need to sort data from this program onto a .txt file

1. in alphabetical order
2. by highest correctAnswers to lowest

   ```
   if usersGroup == a:
   with open("groupA.txt","a+") as f:
       f.write("   {}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))

   elif usersGroup == b:
       with open("groupB.txt","a+") as f:
           f.write("   {}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))

   elif usersGroup == c:
       with open("groupC.txt","a+") as f:
           f.write("   {}:Scored {} in {} seconds.".format(username,correctAnswers,timeTaken))
   else:
       print("Sorry, we can not save your data as the group you entered is not valid.")
   ```

I've tried searching the internet on how to do this but I can not find anything relevant. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What specific problem are you having?

Comment: Well I'm struggling to do the task I've stated above completely.

Answer (score 0):

python comes with a builtin function `sorted(l)` which will return a sorted copy of the sequence `l`; you can even supply your own key or comparison operation, see [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted).

You'll first sort your list of users (or whatever it is that you operate this code excerpt on), and then call your output functions on.

EDIT: I was asked to further simplify my answer; I think this can't really be done, other than what I wrote in a comment:

> As you are new, please read a tutorial on Python. Lists and operations
>   on lists are very central concepts in python, so any good tutorial
>   will make you understand my answer.

Comment: Im quite new to coding so I have no idea what your reply is saying. Can you dumb it down for me a bit?

Comment: Dumbing it down: As you are new, please read a tutorial on Python. Lists and operations on lists are very central concepts in python, so any good tutorial will make you understand my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The sorting algorithm used in the Standard Library (in the `sort` method and the `sorted` function) is stable. This means that the original order is preserved among items that tie under the sorting comparison. If you have ever sorted columns in a spreadsheet, you know what I'm saying.

Suppose you have your data contained in a list of dictionaries like this:

```
{'correctAnswers': 3, 'username': 'Jack', 'timeTaken': 21.7}
```

To achieve your goal, first sort the list by number of correct answers and then by name:

```
scores.sort(key=lambda x: x['correctAnswers'], reverse=True)
scores.sort(key=lambda x: x['username'])
```